# can I specify the return type in the hql words

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, type-conversion

Hi:
I am using hibernate3.6,I meet some problem when do some querying.

Take this hql for exmaple:

```
String hql="select count(distinct ip),sum(bytes) from Entity en where ....
Query q=Session.createQuery(hql);
List<?> list=q.list();
```

Now I can retrive the columen properties from the list by the following way:

```
    String[] properties={"count","sum"};
    for (Object obj : list) {
            Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Object[] props = (Object[]) obj;
            if(properties.length!=props.length) throw ....
            for (int i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
                m.put(properties[i], props[i]);
            }
    }
```

Now,my problem is that,when the hql result no set,the count is 0,but the sum is null. I want it 0 also.

Of course,I can do the converting explicitly if the know the column name and type(they are the count,sum in the above example) of the result table from db,but now I did not know.

That's to say,I can not use something like this:

```
if(props[i]=null) props[i]=0;
m.put(properties[i], props[i]);
```

Since the type of **props[i]** may be string,in this case if **its value is null**, it should be **""**.

So I wonder if I can **sepcify the converting type in the hql words**? maybe someting like this:

> select count(distinct
>   ip), **(long)** sum(bytes) from Entity en
>   where ....
>
> select count(distinct ip),**(converet**
>   ..sum(bytes)) from Entity en where
>   ....

Is this possible?

BWT,I use mysql 5.1.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
@zinan.yumak:

Your answer seems like this;

```
select new Wrapper(count(distinct ip),sum(bytes)) from Entity en where...
```

If so I have to create enougth **extra class like Wrapper** since there are so many types of select in my appliction.like:

```
select new AnotherWrapper(broswer,count(distinct brower)) from Entity en where...

......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a result transformer. Create a model class for your query.
Then add null checks or other checks into your setter methods. Something like this,

```
String hql="select count(distinct ip) as ip, sum(bytes) as bytes from Entity en where ....
Query q=Session.createQuery(hql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Model.class));
```

And in your Model class,

```
class Model {
    private String ip = "";
    private BigDecimal bytes = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public void setIp(String anIp) {
        if ( aString != null) {
            this.ip = anIp;
        }
    }   

    public void setBytes(String aByte) {
        if ( aByte != null) {
            this.byte = aByte;
        }
    }   
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: hguser, i think instanceof checks can help you. Like this, if (props[i] instanceof String ) { if(props[i] != null) { m.put(properties[i], props[i]);
} else {m.put(properties[i], "");
 } } And you repeat same for int type or bigdecimal... By the way you don't have to write constructors if you use resulttransformer.

Comment: Sounds a good idea.But How do I know the type? for example,is the type of the sum() int or long or bigdecimal?

Comment: Before the for loop, insert a debug point and inspect your list variable. You can see element types. sum()'s type is probably BigDecimal.

Comment: hguser, i have a better suggestion for you. If your db supports coalesce command you can solve your problem in sql query. Google for coalesce command.

Comment: Thanks,I tried the ifnull in the hql,it does not work.Now I use the most stupid way which I avoid in the above. For each type of query,I create a dao,the query logic are all the same which is extracted to the abstract dao,the concrete dao will do some post work for the result list from q.list().Since the concrete dao knows which property should be fixed. :) Thank you any way.